# Equation $x=\sin^n(πx/2)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can I prove it?
There exist only one $k \in (0,1)$ such that $k = \sin^n(πk/2)$  when $2 \leq n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Maybe we can find $s \in (0,1)$ such that $s \leq \sin^n(πs/2)$ by differentiating...

Comment: Have you heard of the Intermediate Value Theorem or the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: Yes I've tried to apply it but failed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the continuously differentiable function
$$f(x)=x-\sin^n\frac{\pi x}{2}.$$
**Existence:** Check that for all $n\ge 2$, 
$$f\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}-\sin^n\left(\frac 12\right)>0.$$
On the other hand, notice that for each $n\ge 2$ (by L'Hospital's Rule)
$$\lim_{x\to 1-}\frac{1-x}{1-\sin^n\frac{\pi x}{2}}=\lim_{x\to 1-}\frac{1}{\frac{\pi n}{2}\left(\sin^{n-1}\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\cos\frac{\pi x}{2}}=+\infty,$$
which implies that there exists $y$ sufficiently close to $1$ such that 
$$1-y>1-\sin^n\frac{\pi y}{2},$$
or equivalently, 
$$y-\sin^n\frac{\pi y}{2}<0.$$
Therefore, there exists some $k\in (0,1)$ such that $k=\sin^n\frac{k\pi}{2}$ (by the intermediate value theorem).

**Uniqueness:** Notice that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1-}f(x)=0.$$
If there exist $0<k_1<k_2<1$ such that $f(k_1)=f(k_2)=0$, then according to the (generalized) Rolle's Theorem, there exist $y_1\in (0,k_1)$, $y_2\in (k_1, k_2)$, and $y_3\in (k_2, 1)$ such that 
$$f'(y_1)=f'(y_2)=f'(y_3)=0.$$
However, since
$$f''(x)=-\frac{n\pi^2}{4}\left(\sin^{n-2}\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\left[n\cos^2\frac{\pi x}{2}-1\right],$$
we see that $f''(x)<0$ for all $x\in (0, \frac{2}{\pi}\arccos\sqrt{\frac 1n})$ and $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in (\frac{2}{\pi}\arccos\sqrt{\frac 1n}, 1)$, which implies that $f'(x)$ has at most two zeros on $(0,1)$, a contradiction!